# AngularJS Put Returning 404

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm getting a 404 error with a PUT request when using AngularJS's "$http.put".

Here is my relevant AngularJS code:

```
    /* toggles whether or not the link is disabled */
    toggleLinkStatus: function (isActive, linkGUID) {
        $http.put('/Explorer/Link/ToggleLinkStatus',
                {

                            isActive: isActive,
                            linkGUID: linkGUID
                }
        );
    }
```

And my relevant C# Controller Code:

```
    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult ToggleLinkStatus(Boolean isActive, Guid linkGUID)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

And my WebApiConfig Code

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        /** define routes for Explorer API */
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ExplorerAPI",
            routeTemplate: "Explorer/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? In the Headers for the call I can see that the data is being passed through in the Request Payload:

```
isActive: true
linkGUID: "b94badb3-2917-4129-9ae3-35d2a635f66d"
```

If I do a normal query string PUT using POSTMAN it goes through, but not when I use AngularJS.

**UPDATE**

Here's something interesting, if I use the following angularJS request it goes through:

```
    /* toggles whether or not the link is disabled */
    toggleLinkStatus: function (isActive, linkGUID) {
        $http.put('/Explorer/Link/ToggleLinkStatus',
                {
                    isActive: isActive,
                    linkGUID: linkGUID
                },
                {
                    params:
                        {
                            isActive: isActive,
                            linkGUID: linkGUID
                        }
                }
        );
    }
```

It also works with this:

```
    /* toggles whether or not the link is disabled */
    toggleLinkStatus: function (isActive, linkGUID) {
        $http.put('/Explorer/Link/ToggleLinkStatus',
                {
                },
                {
                    params:
                        {
                            isActive: isActive,
                            linkGUID: linkGUID
                        }
                }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Not sure, have you tried using a '/' after the url?  Have you tried jquery $.put()?  Is LinkController an ApiController?  That works a little differently.  Usually you would just PUT some json to the url with the id in it and expect that a get to the same URL would return the JSON you just put...

Comment: I just put a trailing slash with no results, same error. The LinkController is indeed an ApiController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the controller action to use a class instead of primitive datatypes. MVC Tries to read these from the URI instead the request body.

like this:

```
[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult ToggleLinkStatus(RequestModel model)
{
    // model.IsActive ...
    return Ok();
}

public class RequestModel {
    bool IsActive {get;set;}
    Guid LinkGuid {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: So anytime that I want to grab data from the request body I need to use a class? Even if it's just a single Boolean or a single string object that I'm trying to PUT?

Comment: FYI, this did not work. It doesn't pass the data correctly. The method is called, but the Boolean is always false and the Guid is always all zeroes.

Comment: @RyanDuffing if you're using a single primitve value in the request you can use the `[FromBody]` Attribute to indicate that the value is in the request body. With multiple primitive types you have to use a custom class.

Answer (score 0):

If you're successfully using GET (by doing it in the browser address bar) but not successfully using PUT, then there's something wrong with how you're configuring the route / etc.  I don't see what it is in the code snippet you have here, but there's definitely something amiss in how you've configured your routes.  Perhaps there's an earlier route that matches the GET that's fouling up. It's not Angular's fault. You can test by using the PostMan plugin for Chrome, it'll let you send PUT/POST/DELETE as well as GET and you can see the results.

Comment: I have actually already tried using PostMan with a PUT request and it goes through successfully.

Comment: I guess I meant to say that I used POSTMAN instead of using the browser address bar. I apologize for the misinformation.